# How to stop mattooltip from appearing on focus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a two column table. One column has icons, the other has input text fields. The icons all have mattooltip implemented so that when I hover over an icon, the mattooltip appears. However, when I am in a text input column and I select tab, I go into a table cell that contains an icon which causes the tooltip to appear despite me not hovering. How can I stop this from happening? A possibility is to remove focus from the icons, but what is the best way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Probably a bug in the code. Showing the code would say more than picture though.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try tabindex property

- the element that make tooltip show, put tabindex with a big number
- the input element, put tabindex in order (1, 2, 3 ,4, 5)

So that when clicking tab it should going to all input without go to icon to trigger tooltip